# An echo program, mostly in C and completely from scratch

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, linux, assembly, amd64

This is an `echo` program with no runtime or standard library. It's meant to be compiled with `-nostdlib` on an amd64 Linux system.

```
static signed long mywrite(int fd, const void *buf, unsigned long count) {
    signed long retval;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "syscall" :
        "=a" (retval) :
        "a" (1), "D" (fd), "S" (buf), "d" (count) :
        "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
    return retval;
}

static void myexit(int status) __attribute__((__noreturn__));
static void myexit(int status) {
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "syscall" :
        :
        "a" (60), "D" (status) :

    );
    __builtin_unreachable();
}

static unsigned long mystrlen(const char *str) {
    const char *pos = str;
    while(*pos) ++pos;
    return pos - str;
}

static void writearg(char *str, char end) {
    unsigned long size = mystrlen(str) + 1;
    unsigned long written = 0;
    str[size - 1] = end;
    do {
        signed long result = mywrite(1, str + written, size - written);
        if(result < 0) myexit(1);
        written += result;
    } while(written < size);
}

void _start(void) __attribute__((__naked__, __noreturn__));
void _start(void) {
    __asm__(
        "pop %rdi\n\t"
        "mov %rsp, %rsi\n\t"
        "jmp mymain"
    );
}

static void mymain(int argc, char *argv[]) __attribute__((__noreturn__, __used__));
static void mymain(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc <= 1) {
        myexit(mywrite(1, "\n", 1) != 1);
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc - 1; ++i) {
        writearg(argv[i], ' ');
    }
    writearg(argv[i], '\n');
    myexit(0);
}
```

Some of my concerns:

- Is my program's behavior fully compliant with [the standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)?
- Am I making any unwarranted assumptions that could make my code not work on a future release of Linux (or compiler)? In particular, are popping `argc` and the way I'm overwriting null terminators in `argv` values okay?
- Since my code is Linux-on-amd64-only anyway, are there any other assumptions that I can make? For example, can I assume that Linux will always have continuous `argv` values, and so just make one big `write` call after swapping out all the nulls, instead of one per argument? (I know I'd still have to loop `write` in case of partial writes. I also know I could just copy the strings around myself, but I'd rather write them from where I got them.)
- Instead of having `_start` as an assembly stub and my real code in `mymain`, is there any way I can put my real code in `_start` but still be able to safely get ahold of the command-line arguments?

Comment: Why use `unsigned long` for pointer differences?  Does Linux specify that?  I'd expect `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Because I'd either have to `typedef` it myself, in which case there's no portability win, or `#include` a header from the standard library to get it, which defeats the purpose of what I did entirely.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure the AMD64 ABI does specify that (not 100% sure about the signed-ness, but the result I'm getting is always both small and non-negative, so I don't think it matters).

Comment: Please do not edit the question after it has been answered, especially please do not edit the code after the question has been answered https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my program's behavior fully compliant with the standard for echo?

Code does not process the string as in the [`OPERANDS` section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).  In particular:

Code does not support `\c`: "Suppress the `<newline>` that otherwise follows the final argument in the output. ..."

> Am I making any unwarranted assumptions that could make my code not work on a future release of Linux (or compiler)? In particular, are popping `argc` and the way I'm overwriting null terminators in `argv` values okay?

I see no trouble with `argc`.

Overwriting the null terminators in `argv` [may/may not be OK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25737434/2410359), but is not needed.  I could foresee future restrictions.  Alternative: write the `argv[i]` and then the separator.

> Other issues

No comment.

Comment: Isn't `\c` an XSI requirement, not a POSIX requirement?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica "\c is an XSI requirement".  Unknown how/if required in POSIX. Yet suppressing the \n is useful.

Comment: Also, isn't the question you linked about modifying `argv[x]`, but I'm modifying `argv[x][y]`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That post delves into  modifying `argc, argv, `argv[]` and `argv[][]`.  As C says, "strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program," so your approach looks OK for now.  Since you asked about "unwarranted assumptions that could make my code not work on a future release of Linux", IMO, that is one of those dark corners of C that may disappear in the future.

Comment: "The standard says it's okay, but it might not stay okay since the standard might change" seems like a slippery slope. Isn't that true of literally anything in the standard?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes.  So use good engineering practices.  Just because a corner of the language allows something, do you really want to go there?  For future release concerns, staying toward the middle of the language is better.  Your call.